# VirtualBox machine will not boot up after MaaS commisioning

Tags: virtualbox, maas, openstack

**Question:** Has anyone ever had a problem with a VirtualBox machine not booting up after it's been commissioned and allocated to Admin on MaaS?

> Description: I was able to commision a VirtualBox machine on my MaaS
>   and the Ubuntu-12.04-precise image get installed but when I boot up
>   the virtual machine, I get an boot error. See image below.

[image: Screenshot on Boot Error]

[image: Screenshot of MaaS Controller for VirtualBox machine]

Thanks.

Comment: The error message `FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted!` You should check the Boot Order and make sure it is booting from the correct medium.

Comment: Terry, I've checked the boot system and i even unchecked bootload from network and CD-ROM, I still get the same error. Have you tried commissioning to VirtualBox VMs via MaaS in the past?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the VirtualBox Extension Pack? It offers support for PXE boot. It'a available on the virtualbox.org website on the download page. I believe this is needed for PXE boot to work within virtual box.